# Bucardo what to do on the remote side?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to set-up bucardo in a master-slave setup with pushdelta, however I keep running into the following error when trying to create the sync.

```
bash-4.1$ bucardo_ctl add sync dns source=dns_tables type=pushdelta targetgroup=dns_slaves
WARNING:  Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::Pg::db handle dbname=dns;port=5432 at line 191.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "validate_sync"
SQL statement "SELECT validate_sync('dns')"
PL/Perl function "validate_sync"
Failed to add sync: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema bucardo
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM bucardo.bucardo_delta_targets WHERE tablename=...
                      ^ at line 191. at line 30.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "validate_sync" at /usr/sbin/bucardo_ctl line 3362.
```

Is this because I didn't set-up the remote part properly or?, the master's hba/ident is as follows:

## Master

### pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             postgres                                trust
host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident 
local   all             postgres                                ident     

local   all             bucardo                                 ident     map=bucardo
local   dns             dns                                     md5

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

### pg_ident.conf

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
bucardo         postgres                bucardo
bucardo         bucardo                 bucardo
```

## Slave

### pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident

# 10.0.1.2 is the master
host    bucardo         bucardo         10.0.1.2/32             ident
```

I don't really have an idea what I'm doing wrong, but it probably has something to do with the remote side not being set-up properly, yet I haven't been able to find much on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I completely overlooked that you have to create a superuser on the slave for bucardo itself, after adding that the sync has been successfully enabled.